# Background View shown by default in swipe function

Tags: java, android, swipe

I am trying to implement a swipe function in my app. The swipe function itself is working perfectly. However, the app shows the background view always by default (kind of like scratch to win), take a look at this:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/61ViQ.png)

I tried reversing both the `foreground` and `background` pretty much everywhere, in XML, while referencing them in java, inside the `onChildDraw`, `onChildDrawOver` and all the other methods, but no luck at all.

Once I touch the card to swipe it, the function works correctly (card 2 in the pic). If I release the swipe and return the card to its default position, it'll work correctly (cards 3 and 5 in the pic). Once the activity is created again though, all the cards go to the default blue background (cards 1,4 and 6 in the pic)

EDIT: by the way, cards x,y,z refer to their position on the screen not their content, it just so happens that they are all 1 number each because I try making them as fast as possible to continue testing

Here is my related code:

XML file:

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_margin="0dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:longClickable="true"
android:contextClickable="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/view_foreground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--Foreground elements here-->

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/view_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    >

    <!--Background elements here-->
</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</FrameLayout>
```

There are defined in MyHolder.JAVA:

```
    public RelativeLayout viewBackground, viewForeground;
    ... 
    viewBackground = (RelativeLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_background);
    viewForeground = (RelativeLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_foreground);
    delTxt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.delBackground);
```

And this is the home activity (the one you see in the screenshot):

```
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback =
            new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
                @Override
                public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                      RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
                                      RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

                    //some stuff
                }
                @Override
                public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder
                        viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {

                    final View foregroundView = ((MyHolder)viewHolder).viewForeground;

                    drawBackground(viewHolder, dX, actionState);

                    if (viewHolder.getAdapterPosition() == -1) {
                        return;
                    }

                    getDefaultUIUtil().onDraw(c, recyclerView, foregroundView, dX, dY,
                            actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                            RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY,
                                            int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
                    final View foregroundView = ((MyHolder)viewHolder).viewForeground;

                    drawBackground(viewHolder, dX, actionState);

                    getDefaultUIUtil().onDrawOver(c, recyclerView, foregroundView, dX, dY,
                            actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
                }

                @Override
                public void clearView(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder){
                    final View backgroundView = ((MyHolder)viewHolder).viewBackground;
                    final View foregroundView = ((MyHolder)viewHolder).viewForeground;

                    backgroundView.setRight(0);

                    getDefaultUIUtil().clearView(foregroundView);
                }

                private  void drawBackground(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX,
                                                   int actionState) {
                    final View backgroundView = ((MyHolder)viewHolder).viewBackground;

                    if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE) {
                        //noinspection NumericCastThatLosesPrecision
                        backgroundView.setRight((int) Math.max(dX, 0));
                    }
                }
```

**EDIT**: found the solution, I just flipped both the background and foreground in the XML file, so the foreground goes second, then gave the foreground a white background color.

Comment: thats because styles, go to res folder - values - styles and you can see there the default blue

Comment: The problem isn't really the color itself, I can change it as I want. I want it to be hidden in the background until the user swipes the card.

Answer (score 0):

This problem may be caused by `RecyclerView.notifyDatasetChange()` or `RecyclerView`'s invalidate. When `RecyclerView`'s UI is update, it may create new `ViewHolder` which's view become default. Or when a default `ViewHolder`(eg: card 6 in your pic) being recycled and reused in position 1(card 2 in your pic) also causes your problem.
So you should save the View's status in your gesture callback, and resume View's status in `Adapter.onBindViewHolder()`

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand. Why would saving the View's status mater? Also, can you please provide some code example?

Answer (score 0):

I write a demo below. If don't write code to resume custom view, then the custom view's behavior may be wrong when scroll `RecyclerView`.

RecyclerViewActivity:

```
public class RecyclerViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private Adapter mAdapter;
    private List<ViewStatus> mViewStatuses;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        initData();
        initAdapter();
        LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    }

    private void initData() {
        mViewStatuses = new ArrayList<>();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 100) {
            ViewStatus temp = new ViewStatus();
            temp.isBeanTouched = false;
            temp.text = String.valueOf(i);
            mViewStatuses.add(temp);
            i++;
        }
    }

    private void initAdapter() {
        mAdapter = new Adapter();
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }


    class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(RecyclerViewActivity.this);

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View holderView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_recycler_view, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(holderView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.onBind(position);
        }

        public ViewStatus getItem(int position) {
            return mViewStatuses.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mViewStatuses.size();
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView currentPosTv;
        TextView prePosTv;
        CustomView mCustomView;
        ViewStatus mViewStatus;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            currentPosTv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_current_pos);
            prePosTv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_pre_pos);
            mCustomView = (CustomView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.custom_view);
        }

        public void onBind(int position) {
            mViewStatus = mAdapter.getItem(position);
            // if holder is recycled and reused, then save the pre position in prePosTv
            prePosTv.setText("pre position: " + currentPosTv.getText());
            currentPosTv.setText("current position: " + mViewStatus.text);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            //if do not add code blow to resume customView, then the customView's behavior may be wrong when scroll RecyclerView
//            mCustomView.setSelect(mViewStatus.isBeanTouched);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //save the view status
            mViewStatus.isBeanTouched = !mViewStatus.isBeanTouched;
            mCustomView.setSelect(mViewStatus.isBeanTouched);
        }
    }

    class ViewStatus {
        boolean isBeanTouched = false;
        String text = "";
    }
}
```

CustomView:

```
public class CustomView extends View {

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public CustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    public void setSelect(boolean select) {
        if (select) {
            setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        } else {
            setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
    }
}
```

activity_recycler_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

item_recycler_view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp">

    <com.example.lemon.recyclerviewreuse.CustomView
        android:id="@+id/custom_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tv_current_pos"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_pre_pos"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_current_pos"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="current position:1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_pre_pos"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="pre position: 0"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_current_pos"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This demo shows how `ViewHolder` be  recycled and reused. So we should save item status when user changes the view status and we should resume view's status in `onBindViewHolder()`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the example, I learned something new today :) . Nonetheless, after some testing around I solved the problem in a few easy steps, I'll mention them in my main post.

Comment: Congratulations!